# Gathering a list of dynamic indices

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

Can anyone help figure out how to grab a set of embeddings?

I have some code that predicts the probability of each index, and then selects the max:

```
# U is batch_size x max_sentence_length x embedding_size
scores_per_index = find_start_preds(U ...) # batch_size x max_sentence_length x 1
start_preds = tf.argmax(alpha, axis=1) # batch_size x 1
```

I would like to, if possible, re-grab the word embeddings associated with each start prediction. Is that possible? This is what I'm thinking, but it doesn't work :(

```
u_s = U[:, start_preds, :]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `tf.gather` for what you want, but it only works on the leading indices so you need to reorder:

```
U2 = tf.transpose(U, [1, 0, 2])
u_s = tf.gather(U2, start_preds)
u_s = tf.transpose(u_s, [1, 0, 2])
```